# Place a div over another div without position: absolute or relative and variable height and width

Tags: html, css

I am making an application that uses a website as an interface.
The html look like the following:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#page-1').removeClass("show-me");
  $('#page-2').addClass("show-me");
}, 1000);


setTimeout(function() {
  $('#page-2').removeClass("show-me");
  $('#page-3').addClass("show-me");
}, 2000);
```

```css
div#main {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
div#main > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-property: "opacity,visibility";
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#page-1 {
  background-color: #00f;
}
#page-2 {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#page-3 {
  background-color: #f00;
}
div#main > div.show-me {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="page-1" class="show-me">Page 1</div>
  <div id="page-2">Page 2</div>
  <div id="page-3">Page 3</div>
</div>
```

Each `page` contains data the same way as you would navigate to `www.example.com/page-1`, `www.example.com/page-2` or  `www.example.com/page-3`.

However I want to stay at `www.example.com` and navigate trough pages by fading them in and out.
I got them placed over one another with `position: absolute;top:0;left:0;` but this way `main` won't know the height of the `page` since it's content is absolute.

Therefore i'd like a way to make them fade in and out wiouth the use of `position` or negative margins (since the height of each page is dynamic due to content)

Or maybe you have another way of achieving this effect?

This is for an application, not a webpage that should be indexed by google or something else. So no SEO worries :)

EDIT:
Added a better example.

Comment: Are you currently using JavaScript or jQuery to create your transitions between pages? If so, I would suggest using those to change the height of your "main" div according to the content div height.

Comment: Yeah that works but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without js. The same way you can use margin: 0 auto; to get the page in the center instead of using js to calculate it's position

Comment: I think that CSS is your best solution to position your div content. Using the "absolute" positioning would be the way I would go also. However if you don't assign a height to the "main" div, it should react to the size of the content within. But if you need to assign a height to it, and then dynamically change that height according to the content, then I think JS is your only solution.

Comment: Can you provide your full HTML and CSS, or maybe put it in a fiddle so we can manipulate it for you?

Comment: Yes I need some time to take it out of the app tough. One sec ;)

Comment: Also take a look at this question... It might help you out a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731907/auto-adjust-container-div-height-to-accomodate-absolutely-positioned-child-di?rq=1

Comment: Yeah... was a bit afraid of that. Ok so I'll try to make the active page `display block` and `position static` and then when fading to another page that new page should become `display block` and `position static`. The fading out div then should become `position absolute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding `position: static;` to the 'show-me' class.
This way the main knows the height of it's 'active' child!

When navigating first the active page class 'show-me' is removed, so it becomes position absolute again and starts to fade-out.
The next page gets the class 'show-me'.
Now becomes static so the main knows the new page's height and follows it.
And the new page fade's in as it should!

For a short moment (which you cannot see as far as I tested) the main div has no content and becomes small again. If it contains a background image you may see a little flicker but I think it's to fast for that so it shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Well I hope that I helped get you to this conclusion. Please up vote anything that helped you get to this answer, or clarify how you go to your answer so that future readers can see how you did it also.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You did make me look at my problem better, however the person who made me think of the answer has removed it's comment for some reason... It was under yours: 'Also take a look at this question...'  and I commented on it with: ' 
Yeah... was a bit afraid of that ....'

Answer (score 0):

I would have to recomend [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) library for this.  It's pretty much what it was built for. I have been using it recently to make a custom app for our company and it's really quite good.  Although a little bit tricky to pick up initially it's not as steep a learning curve as some other libraries I have used in the past.

(would have made this a comment, but I cant :-(  )

Comment: What exactly should I be using of the library? which API methods?

Comment: Using the Page container : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/ you can transition pages through your app whilst maintaining header and footer info.  It's fully themable and only depends on the jquery lib.  You can either download a local copy of the min.js files or link to them through a hosted server.  Also, everything is focused to the viewport by the lib, no need to much more than tweak it here and there.